# Git rebase mentions conflicts, but I haven't touched *anything* locally

Tags: git

If I understand `git merge master` and `git rebase master` properly, they are supposed to bring the changes in the `master` branch into the local working branch. If this is correct, I have confirmed that no files locally have been modified, but yet there are still conflicts when merging.

For example, here's what `git status` looks like for me:

```
 user@kali > ~/folder > > test > git status
On branch test
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/test'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
 user@kali > ~/folder > > test >
```

So if my branch is up-to-date with the `test` branch and the `master` branch has made changes, why would i get a conflict when running `git rebase master`?

[image]

Comment: Our beloved EOL format changes? What does the conflict look like? Two blocks with the full file content each?

Comment: Your understanding of rebase/merge is not correct.  If you merge or rebase `master` into some other branch, and `master` has commits not contained in `test`, then in general you could get conflicts.  There is nothing surprising happening here at all.

Comment: Gotcha. Considering I don't have any files changed, I figured it'd just pull down changes, just like a `git pull` would. Thanks for the clarification. @eftshift0 the conflict was just that the `entrypoint.sh` file contained an added 3 lines in the middle of the file.